# ReactJS Checkboxes from json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux

I have the following json structure , which is dynamic and not fixed.

start:

```
[{A: [{
            a: [{1: true}, {2: false}]
        }, {
            b: [{1: true}, {2: false}]
        }]},{ B: [{
            x: [{1: true}, {2: false}]
        }, {
            y: [{1: true}, {2: false}]
        }]}
```

I need to render check boxes based on the true or false value. I am able to render the checkboxes from state where json is stored. How do i change the state to false o clicking the checkbox.

Comment: I would start by simplifying your state. Can you share the code you already wrote?

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code with react?

Comment: First create a primary key in all your object which will be used for indexing/navigating. Then attach onClick to each checkbox and pass the data attached to that checkbox to the click handler. Inside your click handler search for that object using the data you received from the checkbox onclick call. Change the value to false and that will do.